# How to select visible element using XPath or CSS?

Tags: javascript, css, xpath, internet-explorer-8, selenium-webdriver

I want to select the apply button in the following code. There are two buttons and only one button is visible.

```
//input[@value='Apply' and @id='btn' and @name='btn' and not(ancestor::td[contains(@style,'display:none')])]
```

I have written above XPath to select the visible one but in web driver it says unable to access the element. (browser - IE8)

```
<table class="ColumnTable" cellspacing="0">
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td>
            <div id="dashboard~120" class="Section" style="" headeron="" minimized="false" rendered="false">
               <table class="SectionT" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                  <tbody>
                     <tr>
                        <td style=" display:none;">
                           <div id="dashboard~Contents" style="">
                              <table style="width:100%">
                                 <tbody>
                                    <tr height="100%">
                                       <td class="EItem" valign="TOP" align="CENTER" colspan="2" style="">
                                          <div id="EmbedViewd" reloadinline="">
                                             <div id="NavDone" style="display:;">
                                                <div id="Result" result="Prompt">
                                                   <table class="ViewTable" cellspacing="0">
                                                      <tbody>
                                                         <tr>
                                                            <td>
                                                               <div id="newLayout">
                                                                  <form style="margin: 0;" method="post" action="javascript:void(null);">
                                                                     <div style="">
                                                                        <table class="PromptView" style="">
                                                                           <tbody>
                                                                              <tr>
                                                                                 <td class="ButtonsCell">
                                                                                    <input id="btn" class="button" type="button" tabindex="0" value="Apply" name="btn" style="background-color: rgb(240, 240, 240);">
                                                                                 </td>
                                                                              </tr>
                                                                           </tbody>
                                                                        </table>
                                                                     </div>
                                                                  </form>
                                                               </div>
                                                            </td>
                                                         </tr>
                                                      </tbody>
                                                   </table>
                                                </div>
                                             </div>
                                          </div>
                                       </td>
                                    </tr>
                                 </tbody>
                              </table>
                           </div>
                        </td>
                     </tr>
                  </tbody>
               </table>
            </div>
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>
            <div id="dashboard~121" class="Section" style="" headeron="true" minimized="false" rendered="false">
               <table class="SectionT" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                  <tbody>
                     <tr>
                        <td>
                           <div id="dashboard~Contents" style="">
                              <table class="SectionTD" style="width:100%; border-top:none;">
                                 <tbody>
                                    <tr height="100%">
                                       <td class="EItem" valign="TOP" align="CENTER" colspan="2" style="">
                                          <div id="EmbedViewd" reloadinline="">
                                             <div id="NavDone" style="display:;">
                                                <div id="Result" result="Prompt">
                                                   <table class="ViewTable" cellspacing="0">
                                                      <tbody>
                                                         <tr>
                                                            <td>
                                                               <div id="newLayout">
                                                                  <form style="margin: 0;" method="post" action="javascript:void(null);">
                                                                     <div style="">
                                                                        <table class="PromptView" style="">
                                                                           <tbody>
                                                                              <tr>
                                                                                 <td class="ButtonsCell">
                                                                                    <input id="btn" class="button" type="button" tabindex="0" value="Apply" name="btn" style="background-color: rgb(240, 240, 240);">
                                                                                 </td>
                                                                              </tr>
                                                                           </tbody>
                                                                        </table>
                                                                     </div>
                                                                  </form>
                                                               </div>
                                                            </td>
                                                         </tr>
                                                      </tbody>
                                                   </table>
                                                </div>
                                             </div>
                                          </div>
                                       </td>
                                    </tr>
                                 </tbody>
                              </table>
                           </div>
                        </td>
                     </tr>
                  </tbody>
               </table>
            </div>
         </td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

My question is there anyway other work around for this issue. I think there are plenty of ways to write the above xpath am i right?

Answer (score 3):

You could try the following in case this is a Selenium issue:

```
//input[@value='Apply'][@id='btn'][@name='btn']  
       [not(ancestor::td[contains(@style,'display:none')])]
```

It's the same expression with the same result, but as mentioned here [Xpath does not work with Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20355393/xpath-does-not-work-with-selenium) it's possible that Selenium has an issue with evaluating `and` in XPath.

Another issue I just want to mention is that you shoudn't use the same `id` for multiple elements, `id`s should be unique. Otherwise your HTML is not valid. When you change the ids to unique values, it'd be possible to reduce the XPath match conditions.

Comment: Not match `display: none`(include space) or `display: none;` or `display:none;`.

Answer (score -1):

Selecting an element using xpath:

Selecting the first element:

//div[@id='dashboard~120']descendant::input[@id='btn'].Click;

Selecting the second element:

//div[@id='dashboard~121']descendant::input[@id='btn'].Click;